# Salesforce API for saving data in Salesforce database using any other language (Cakephp)

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, database, rest-service

Friends,

I am a web developer`(Cakephp)`. I am working on the `XYZ project`. In that project I have many Contact forms example - contact us form, user details form, enrollment form etc. I developed that project in `Cakephp 2.0` everything is working fine. What I have to do for this ?

***Requirement :-***

When user will submit a form details it will save on `Salesforce` database.. ***I need to create a Lead in CRM (Salesforce).*** And I need to do database functionality using API (Create a lead, submit data, alter data etc.)

I am having my `salesforce login credientials`.

I want to know is there any `API` or something so that when I will submit my form in website That same data will save in `Salesforce` database..

***What I have tried ?***

I have checked in `salesforce` doc and Google it I found something

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/REST_API

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm

But I am confused how to integrate with my `Cakephp` project and how to use `salesforce API`..

If any one integrated this please help me out !!

Thanks !!

Comment: I edit my question with some more details !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For lead generation i would recommend to use the web2lead form generated by Salesforce itself.

There is an option that a salesforce administrator can click on to generate a web form for a web2lead page. this pages uses a form action that will create a lead in salesforce.  Advantage here is that you don't need to code anything, just add styling to the page.

then you don't need api's or users to connect to salesforce.

Also an advantage is that if there are assignment rules in salesforce with the api you need to code which ones need to run. with the web2lead form this is not necessary.

Comment: What I want i dont wanna do anything from salesforce, when I will submit form I want to call API or some method and I want to create lead and want to save data ???

Comment: I use a PHP cUrl call to submit about 90% of my inquiries to the Web2Lead form from my server. The remaining 10% have special routing so I submit via the SOAP API to bypass the W2L lead routing rules.

Answer (score 1):

bakery.cakephp.org/articles/cwestonr/2010/01/26/example-datasource-for-salesforce-enterprise-1

The above blog explains on integration using php sfdc toolkit.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_13.1

The above is link to php toolkit .Note that this integration described is through SOAP

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php

If REST API is used you can get some hint on how to proceed from above link

Comment: Thanks for your help !! I want to create a Lead when I will submit my form.. Is it work ??